# Access controls in created TabPage from separate function C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

I have the following code in my WinForms C# app:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var txtbox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            TabPage createdtabpage = new TabPage("I am a tab");
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(createdtabpage);
            createdtabpage.Controls.Add(txtbox2);
        }
```

And I want to access the text of `txtbox2` when a separate button is clicked. I have this code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Either this:
           string text = txtbox2.Text;
           //or maybe this:
           string text = createdtabpage.Controls[txtbox2]
        }
```

However, this code doesn't work because the variables are not accessible to outside functions.
Does anybody have a good way to access these TabPage controls from an outside function?
Thanks for any help

Comment: The reason you can normally access something like `txtbox2.Text` is because when you create a tab at _design time_, the designer creates the control as a property of the form. When you create something on the fly (at _run time_) there's no property. Instead, you need to set the new tab's and the new control's `Name` properties and then fish the tab out of the Tab Control's Pages collection and the control out of the tabs Controls collection

Comment: Either what @Flydog57 said, or create a property/field to store `txtbox2`

Comment: @Flydog57 can you give an example of how to do that with code

Comment: Sorry, my programming from my phone keyboard isn't up to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the control tab, the tab is selected and then the desired control is found by name.

use this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
     var textBox = (RichTextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["txtbox2"];
     MessageBox.Show(textbox.Text);
}
```

Without a name, you have to navigate through all the controls, and for example, if you have multiple richTextBox controls, know the order in which they are located.

```
foreach (Control control in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
{
    if(control is RichTextBox)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(control.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: To do that, you need to set the `Name` property of the control to `"txtBox2"` when you create it. But, that's the idea

Comment: You should bail out with `break;` inside the `if`